# How to select rows if customer has purchased the same product 3x in a row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables, [customer_list] and [purchase_history].
I want to find list of all customers whose most recent three purchases have been a particular product three times in a row.

Table example below:

```
customer_list          purchase_history
id |  name             id | cust_id| product_id | purchase_date
1  |  Alan              1 |    1   |     AA     |  2019-06-05
2  |  Bob               2 |    1   |     BB     |  2019-1-13
3  |  Carol             3 |    2   |     CC     |  2018-11-23
4  |  David             4 |    1   |     AA     |  2017-03-12
                        5 |    3   |     CC     |  2019-09-25
                        6 |    1   |     FF     |  2019-04-31
                        7 |    1   |     AA     |  2019-02-14
                        8 |    4   |     AA     |  2019-03-05
                        9 |    4   |     AA     |  2019-04-10
                       10 |    2   |     AA     |  2019-02-24
                       11 |    4   |     AA     |  2019-05-16
```

I'm playing around with code similar to below but appreciate if someone could help out too:

```
select * from customer_list t1 where EXISTS(
    select * from purchase_history t2 where **latest 3 product_id** is like 'AA' )
```

My final result should be like this:

```
  customer_list
  id  | name
  4   | David
```

Only 'David' should appear in the result because his last 3 most recent purchases were the particular product selected "AA".

I'm running MSSQL 2008 on Windows Server 2008.

Comment: I think you might need PLSQL for that.

Comment: So you define three times the same date as three times in a row?  Are there anny other cases which you call three times in a row?

Comment: Also what in cases of four the same dates?

Comment: On a completely unrelated note,it is probably time to upgrade from SQL Server 2008. It is very, very old. Also, the [End Of Life date is in two weeks (9th July 2019)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/sql-server/sql-server-2008), in addition Windows Server reaches end of life in January 2020.

Comment: For simplicity, I amended the dates in the example table that were duplicated. In my real table I have date/time format YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cross apply` and aggregation:

```
select c.id
from customer_list c cross apply
     (select top (3) ph.*
      from purchase_history ph
      where ph.cust_id = c.id
      order by ph.purchase_date desc
     ) ph3
group by c.id
having min(ph3.product_id) = max(ph3.product_id) and
       min(ph3.product_id) = 'AA';
```

If you might have fewer than three records in the purchase history, then change the having clause to:

```
having min(ph3.product_id) = max(ph3.product_id) and
       min(ph3.product_id) = 'AA' and
       count(*) = 3;
```

Comment: I think this would need a further having clause - `COUNT(ph3.product_id) = 3`, otherwise customers that have only ever bought one product would be returned if that product is `AA`

Comment: This code brings up an error:

Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
The multi-part identifier "ph.product_id" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
The multi-part identifier "ph.CRC" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
The multi-part identifier "ph.product_id" could not be bound.

Comment: @Husam2509 . . . That was a typo.  It should be (and is now) `ph3`.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you could use a construct like this to get the maximum amount of sequential orders of the same product per customer:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id, product_id ORDER BY cust_id ASC, purchase_date DESC) as rn
```

Use this in a subquery and group it by cust_id, product_id and get the max(rn) and you should have what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with this to sequence orders by client (in descending purchase date order) and assign a sequential row number.

```
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id ORDER BY cust_id ASC, purchase_date DESC) RowNumber, *
from purchase_history
```

(You don't the need all the fields. I just left the * in so it was easy to verify.)

Wrap that in an outer query that filters the derived row number to limit to 3 most recent orders by customer and group by customer and product. If all 3 of the most recent orders for the customer are the same product, `HAVING COUNT(*) = 3` will get what you the customers you want. You can then join or subquery to get the customer_list columns.

Here's the whole query:

```
select * from customer_list where id in (
select cust_id  from (
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id ORDER BY cust_id ASC, purchase_date DESC) RowNumber, 
cust_id, product_id
from purchase_history
) s1
where RowNumber <= 3
group by cust_id, product_id
having count(*) = 3
)
```